# When to use V instead of a decimal in Cobol Pic Clauses

Tags: cobol

Studying for a test right now and can't seem to wrap my head around when to use `"V"` for a decimal instead of an actual decimal in PIC clauses. I've done some research but can't find anything I understand. Only been learning cobol for about a week, so is there like a rule of thumb here? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Any feedback on this?

Comment: Any feedback on this?

Answer (score 3):

You use an actual decimal-point when you want to "output" a value which has decimal places, like a report line, a position on a screen, an item in an output file which is going to a "different" system which doesn't understand the format with an implied decimal pace.

That's what the V is, it is an implied decimal place. It tells the compiler where to align results from calculations, MOVEs, whatever. Computer chips, and the machine instructions they support, don't know about actual decimal points for their internal processing.

COBOL is a language with fixed-length fields. The machine instructions don't need to know where the decimal point is (effectively it can deal with everything as integer values) but the compiler does, and the compiler has to do the correct scaling and alignment of results.

Storing on your own files, use `V`, the implied decimal place.

For data which is to be "human readable" or read by a system which cannot understand your character set, cannot scale what looks like an integer, use an actual decimal-point, `.` (for computer-readable stuff, you can sometimes use a separate scaling factor, if that is more convenient for the receiving system).

Basically, `V` for internal, `.` for external, should be a rule of thumb to get you there.

Which COBOL are you using? I'm surprised it is not covered in your documentation.